# T-SQL, repeated same scalar subquery performance in views

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, subquery

Below is a simple query that retrieves Students and their exam results. The same student can take the same exam multiple times. The subqueries retrieve the latest exam results for each student. As you can see, the Line X (which retrieves the latest Exam ID) is exactly the same in every subquery for each row. How to store or cache the result of Line X to prevent three times execution for each row?
I cannot use stored procedure or functions for this task, it has to be a VIEW for additional filtering.

```
SELECT S.*,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ExamAnswers WHERE 
  IsCorrectAnswer IS NOT NULL AND
  IsCorrectAnswer = 1 AND 
  ExamID = 
  (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM Exams E WHERE E.StudentID = S.ID ORDER BY ID DESC) --Line X
) CorrectAnswerCount,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ExamAnswers EA WHERE 
  EA.IsCorrectAnswer IS NOT NULL AND
  EA.IsCorrectAnswer = 0 AND 
  EA.ExamID = 
  (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM Exams E WHERE E.StudentID = S.ID ORDER BY ID DESC) --Line X
) WrongAnswerCount,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ExamAnswers WHERE 
  IsCorrectAnswer IS NULL AND
  ExamID = 
  (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM Exams E WHERE E.StudentID = S.ID ORDER BY ID DESC) --Line X
) UnansweredQuestionCount

FROM Students S
```

Comment: You could of cause make a function, but it will still execute 3 times, so that would only be for clarity and DRY consideration, I doubt this effort will be worth your time, but am curious to see if somebody are familiar with a way you can actually do this in a view i doubt it much :)

Comment: `IsCorrectAnswer IS NOT NULL AND IsCorrectAnswer = 1` should just be written `IsCorrectAnswer = 1` - if it meets that it is guaranteed to meet `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Side note: Just because a subquery appears three times in a query doesn't necessarily mean it is *executed* three times. Usually the optimizer should spot that and the result will be reused (if it doesn't find a completely other way that is). Remember SQL is declarative not imperative. When in doubt, check the plan.

Comment: @stickybit - The SQL Server optimiser virtually never (if ever) does common sub query expression refactoring to combine similar sub queries. This is the case even when they only appear once in the query text - such as `COALESCE((sub_query), 1)` - which will have two instances of the `sub_query` tree in the execution plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT S.*,
       CA.*
FROM   Students S
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN IsCorrectAnswer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CorrectAnswerCount,
                           SUM(CASE WHEN IsCorrectAnswer = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WrongAnswerCount,
                           SUM(CASE WHEN IsCorrectAnswer IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UnansweredQuestionCount
                    FROM   ExamAnswers EA
                    WHERE  EA.ExamID = (SELECT TOP(1) ID
                                        FROM   Exams E
                                        WHERE  E.StudentID = S.ID
                                        ORDER  BY ID DESC)) CA
```

Comment: I think should use `OUTER APPLY`. Unless OP can confirmed that all Student will have row(s) in ExamAnswers

Comment: @Squirrel - nope. This is a scalar aggregate so always returns a single row even if the table was empty. See [Fun with Scalar and Vector Aggregates](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html)

Comment: You are right. Didn't noticed the aggregate

Answer (score -1):

What about this approach :

```
WITH
T AS
(
SELECT Student_id,
       SUM(CASE IsCorrectAnswer WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS COUNT_TRUE,
       SUM(CASE IsCorrectAnswer WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS COUNT_FALSE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN IsCorrectAnswer IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS COUNT_UNKNOWN
FROM   ExamAnswers AS EA 
WHERE  EA.ExamID = (SELECT MAX(ID) 
                    FROM   Exams E 
                    WHERE  E.StudentID = S.ID)
GROUP  BY Student_id
)
SELECT S.*, COUNT_TRUE, COUNT_FALSE, COUNT_UNKNOWN
FROM   Students AS S
       JOIN T ON S.ID = T.Student_id
```

Comment: This doesn't at all have the same semantics as the original query. For each student it needs to find the corresponding exam for that student with the highest id and return values from `ExamAnswers` for that exam in the same row as the student info. Your query is not doing anything even vaguely similar

Comment: Sorry I correct it

Comment: It still won't work - the initial CTE has `WHERE  E.StudentID = S.ID` but there is no such alias as `S` in scope there

Comment: With all columns having the same name ID, ID, ID....  it is very difficult to answer your demand. Please correct your post with the DDL definition of your tables...